# Extract numbers from String on ATMega168

Tags: c, atmega, string

I try to separate and parse two numbers out of a string, one is a float and one is an int. So I do this...

```
char packet_buffer[24];
float dist_float;
uint32_t quality;
uint32_t distance;
strncpy(packet_buffer, ": 2.846m,0089", 24); 
memmove(packet_buffer, packet_buffer+1, strlen(packet_buffer)); //Remove leading colon
sscanf(packet_buffer, "%fm,%d", &dist_float, &quality);
distance = (uint32_t)(dist_float*1000);
```

This returns 96 for quality and 0 for distance... but running it with Ideone works. Did I overlook something in combination with the ATMega?

I'd expect 89 for quality and 2846 for distance.

Edit: After adding the build parameters suggested by Filo, the output looks like this

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.2.150\include"  -O1 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega168p -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.2.150\gcc\dev\atmega168p" -c -gdwarf-2 -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -fdata-sections  -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt -lm -MD -MP -MF "src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o"   -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c" 
    Finished building: ../src/main.c
```

Comment: Have you configured the standard library so that it can handle those things? In a micro there is usually a much less capable library especially for things like string parsing. Usually there is a compiler option but I don't work with ATMegas, so can't tell you details.

Comment: "*This returns 96 for quality and 0 for distance...*", and what do you expect? 100 for quality and 2.846 for distance?

Comment: @Arsenal: You mean configure to use the `sscanf` function? Where would I do that?
@Harry: I'd expect 89 for quality and 2846 for distance

Comment: Do you printf the variables or inspect with a debugger? If printf then please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you find yourself using float numbers and stdio.h on a 8-bit kitchen sink MCU, you are doing it terribly wrong. Things to study: how C code translates to machine code, what is a FPU, fixed point arithmetic. Also strncpy is a dangerous function that should be avoided.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to simplify everything

Answer (score 0):

AVR libc has stdio functions in two flavors, one small (without floats) and another full-size with all features. See for example the description of vscanf from [AVR libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html),
basically you have to build with:

```
-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt -lm
```

And if you want to `printf` the variables you also have to add:

```
-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm
```

Comment: Any chance you know how to do this in AtmelStudio 7?

Comment: "atmel studio compiler flags" https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/GUID-ECD8A826-B1DA-44FC-BE0B-5A53418A47BD/index.html?GUID-9241847D-2474-41F8-86D0-BD8BCD80BC8E

Comment: So I added those flags to the Misc flags of the AVR/GNU C Compiler but the outcome is the same. Do I have to put it somewhere else?

Comment: First clean and fully rebuild the project, if it does not help, then best if you post the whole output of your build process, there should be a console or something with gcc commands and their outputs.

Comment: See my edit in the start post...